# Using concexity property of norm function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space. Let $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ be in $X$ such that  there exists a non zero $\lambda_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda_0$ to be<0, such that $\|x+\lambda_0y\|<\|x\|$. Can anyone tell me how by convexity of the norm function $\|x+\lambda y\|<\|x\|$
for $\lambda \ in [\lambda_0, 0).$?

Comment: @D.B. I don't see your point. I think you misread the question

Comment: @user535666 If $f(t) := ||x+ty||$, then $f$ is convex and so $f(\lambda) \le \alpha f(\lambda_0)+(1-\alpha)f(0) < ||x||$ where $\alpha \in (0,1]$ is s.t. $\lambda = \alpha \lambda_0+(1-\alpha)_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y_0=\lambda_0y$, then $\|x+y_0\|<\|x\|$. By triangle inequality (or the convexity property as you mention) we have, for $\gamma\in(0,1]$,
$$
\|x+\gamma y_0\|=\|\gamma(x+y_0)+(1-\gamma) x\|\leq\gamma\|x+y_0\|+(1-\gamma)\|x\|<\|x\|,
$$
that is to say, for $\lambda\in\lambda_0(0,1]$, we have
$$
\|x+\lambda y\|<\|x\|.
$$